# How to set a ref when using React.cloneElement on a Function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a `Tooltip` component and came across the following problem -

> Function components cannot be given refs

My code looks like this

Component that includes the `Tooltip`:

```
<Tooltip title="Title" description="Description">
   <Selection value={copy.value} label={copy.label} />
</Tooltip>
```

Tooltip component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const Tooltip = props => {
   const myRef = useRef()

   const child = React.cloneElement(props.children, {
      onMouseEnter: () => { /* placeholder */ },
      onMouseLeave: () => { /* placeholder */ },
      ref: myRef,
   })

   const TooltipOverlay = () => {
      // will be a div wrapped in react Portal
      return null
   }

   return (
      <>
         {child}
         <TooltipOverlay />
      </>
   )
}

export default Tooltip
```

My goal is to not have a visible wrapper in the DOM like div/span or similar.
I need the ref to be able to relatively position `TooltipOverlay` in the `Tooltip` component.
All solutions are welcome as long as long as goals above are fulfilled.

I saw this done in `rsuite` library, not sure how.

Comment: `key` and `ref` are preserved in cloned elements (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). Are you trying to pass/forward a ref to a functional child component? Is that the issue?

Comment: You have to add a wrapper for `props.children`, even `rsuite` does it: https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/master/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.tsx what exactly you saw? "I saw this done in rsuite library, not sure how"

Comment: @DrewReese No, I've not defined any refs that would go into Tooltip.

@DennisVash I used https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/master/src/Whisper/Whisper.tsx for a tooltip functionality in the past. Unlike `material-ui`s tooltip, `rsuite` `Whisper` component works with any type of children, including function component like in my example. I lack the knowledge of React to understand how they achieve it.

Comment: I literally shared the code, click on the link, they add a wrapper as mentioned

Comment: I think you misunderstood. `React.cloneElement` only preserves `key` and `ref` of the components they clone, it can't inject them as they are not props that are passed. It seems you are trying to pass the `myRef` to the children, which you would need to forward, i.e. via `React.forwardRef`, or use a wrapper element as Dennis points out.

Comment: @DrewReese Mind giving an example for my case? I've tried many ways, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and couldn't find a way to do what you wanted.

As a workaround and I guess the usual way is to let the user of the `Tooltip` pass the `ref` down and then you can intercept it with `forwardRef`.

```
const Tooltip = forwardRef((props, myRef) => {
  // now you can clone without a ref and have access to the ref.
})
```

The user of the tooltip needs to pass a ref however:

```
const childRef = useRef()

<Tooltip ref={childRef}>
  <div ref={childRef} />
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `child` you are passing to the Tooltip is a component, You should pass props to the tag of that Component.

```
// NOTE: Selection is a Component
<Tooltip title="Title" description="Description">
    <Selection value={copy.value} label={copy.label} />
</Tooltip>


// NOTE: Selection
const Selection = (props) => {
  // NOTE: in your code, props will be onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave
  // return <div {...props}>{props.children}</div>
  return <div
            onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter} 
            onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}>
            {props.children}
         </div>
}
```

maybe this will work for you.